# Alignment problem between multiple line "bmatrices"

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, matrices

I'm having problems trying to align single and multiple line `bmatrices`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    x = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}\\
    y = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
    z = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I guess the solution would be to force the same matrix tracing used in the one with the biggest amount of lines, but how to do it?

The above example led to a false interpretation of the problem. What I want is to have the alignment on the beginning of each bracket:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    x = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&6&5 \end{bmatrix}\\
    y = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
    z = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&4\\3&2&4&1\\5&4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

and the answers no longer work:

[image]

Comment: You might want to clarify that it is the vertical alignment of the columns you are talking about. Not quite obvious without an image. It is due to the width of the fences being different. It could probably be hacked but it may be very hard to do since it is dealing with internal `\left ... \right` constructions

Comment: @daleif I didn't even consider the horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\lone
\newcommand\fitto[2]{%
  \setlength\lone{\widthof{$#1$}}%
  \makebox[\lone][c]{$#2$}%
}
\begin{document}
\def\x{\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}}
\begin{align*}
    x = &\fitto{\x}{\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}}\\
    y = &\fitto{\x}{\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}}\\
    z = &\fitto{\x}{\x}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something like that, but I don't think it is worth doing. It takes to much work in general.

Comment: @daleif  I understand your point, but in general with such a macro approach, all the matrices to be stacked have to be known in advance, so that the widest can be determined.  To do it "automatically" would require a single call in which all the matrices were simultaneously passed to the macro for assessment, along with the auxiliary material.  I think that would quickly grow more complicated than this approach, in which the user picks the widest array manually, and tells the macro to fit to it.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly enough, there is no easy override to the alignment of the `align`-like environments. They always follow (correctly) a `r`ight-`l`eft (R&L) alignment. You can change that by using a different preamble (`align@preamble`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{rcalign*}{%
  \def\align@preamble{%
    &\hfil
      \strut@
      \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{####}$}%
      \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
      \set@field
      \tabskip\z@skip
    &\hfil\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}####}$}%
      \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
      \set@field
      \hfil
      \tabskip\alignsep@
  }%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne%
  }
  {\endalign}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  x = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix} \\
  y = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix} \\
  z = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{rcalign*}
  x = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix} \\
  y = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix} \\
  z = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{rcalign*}
\end{document}
```

The above example defines the environment `rcalign*` that has `r`ight-`c`entre (R&C) alignment. This only works if you use the operator with the R-column (left-hand side) and most certainly don't include anything other than these matrices in the C-column (right-hand side).

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

(Updated) (variant added, following egreg's suggestion) (done in two steps...)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}\tabcolsep0pt
  \begin{tabular}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
     x = {} &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}\\
\noalign{\vskip\jot}
     y = {} &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
\noalign{\vskip\jot}
     z = {} &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
% former proposal 
% \begin{equation*}
%    \begin{matrix}
%      x & = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}\\
% \noalign{\vskip\jot}
%      y & = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
% \noalign{\vskip\jot}
%      z & = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
%    \end{matrix}
% \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

(I am not sure whether the `\displaystyle` are useful; not in the case at hand but in other situations perhaps)
[image: aligned matrices]

The commented out code gave:

[image: aligned matrices]

And here it is now with egreg's tabular column specification (I had forgotten that `@{}` is a better way to kill intercolumn). I have also taken out the `{}`'s from the `x={}`, `y={}`, etc... and added the last matrix typeset normally to compare the spacing.

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$\displaystyle}r<{$}@{}>{$\displaystyle{}}c<{$}@{}}
     x = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}\\
\noalign{\vskip\jot}
     y = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
\noalign{\vskip\jot}
     z = &\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     z = \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: aligned matrices]

I had not yet moved the `=` signs to the location suggested by `egreg`. Here it is:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$\displaystyle}r<{$}@{}>{$\displaystyle{}}c<{$}@{}}
     x &=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}\\
\noalign{\vskip\jot}
     y &=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
\noalign{\vskip\jot}
     z &=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1\\4&4&4 \end{bmatrix}
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: aligned matrices]

Comment: Probably `@{}>{$\displaystyle}r<{$}@{}>{$\displaystyle{}}c<{$}@{}}` would be a better specification, with the input `x &= \begin{bmatrix}...` that conforms to the usual conventions.

Comment: @egreg --- thanks! incorporated to the answer. No wait, I understood half of your suggestion, I need to re-do it. Ok, done now.

Answer (score 0):

With the package `nicamatrix`, you have a key `delimiters/max-width`. When this key is in force, all the delimiters of the environments of `nicematrix` (`{pNiceMatrix}`, `{bNiceMatrix}`, etc.) are drawn with a width equal to the maximal width of such delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

{\NiceMatrixOptions{delimiters/max-width}
\begin{align*}
x & = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix} \\
y & = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 1 
\end{bNiceMatrix} \\
z & = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
4 & 4 & 4
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]